# Подскажите, как можно сверстать данный блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите пожалуйста, как сверстать нижнюю часть блока. не пойму как делать эти линии с цифрами[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: #273947;
}

.block {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.num {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.num span {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #273947;
  position: relative;
}

.num span::after,
.num span::before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.num span::before {
  left: 0;
}

.num span::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="num"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="num"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="num"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="num"><span>4</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```